# Numpy "sort like" function

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

Say I have two arrays, `v` and `w`:

```
v=np.arange(10)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
w=np.random.random(10,)
array([ 0.20224634,  0.19145386,  0.44607429,  0.53601637,  0.29148741,
        0.62670435,  0.95371219,  0.63634805,  0.48733178,  0.17155278])
```

I can sort `w` like this:

```
np.sort(w)
array([ 0.17155278,  0.19145386,  0.20224634,  0.29148741,  0.44607429,
        0.48733178,  0.53601637,  0.62670435,  0.63634805,  0.95371219])
```

I would like to sort `v` in the same way as `w`. E.g. so that element 9 moves to element 0 and so on until `v` becomes:

```
array([9, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 5, 7, 6])
```

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?

If not, how would you do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the order using `np.argsort`:

```
order = np.argsort(w)
```

And then just sort both arrays:

```
w = w[order]
v = v[order]
```